# Schengen Entry/Exit SQL Calculator

Tags: sql, t-sql

The EU Schengen Agreement allows tourist from 50 some countries to stay 90 out of the last 180 days.  If you entered on February 1, 2023 and stayed for 90 days May 1, 2023; for each day until the end of the year, how many days could you stay again inside the Schengen zone?

Using Excel I calculated that if I returned on September 1, 2023, over the last 180 days I had been inside the zone for 59 days as the start of the 180 days is March 5, 2023.  The running total remains 59 days until October 30, 2023 when all the days inside the zone are from the September 1, 2023 entry.

Is there a SQL statement that would do this calculation for me?

I did create a temp table with 2 years of dates and flag the dates inside and outside the zone.  But this is hard coded to those dates.  If the code could be generalized it would allow planning.  Showing the earliest possible return (August 1, 2023) and/or the required exit date if you are allowed back on that specific date.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Vaca
CREATE TABLE #Vaca
(
    VacationDate date
    ,[Location] nvarchar(100)
    ,InEu int
)

DECLARE @n int = 0
        ,@StartDate date = N'2022/06/01'



WHILE @n < 730
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Vaca
    (
        VacationDate
        ,[Location]
        ,InEu
    )
    VALUES (@StartDate
            ,CASE WHEN @StartDate BETWEEN N'2023/02/01' and N'2023/05/01'THEN N'EU'
                    WHEN @StartDate BETWEEN N'2023/09/01' and N'2023/11/29'THEN N'EU'
                    ELSE N'Outside EU'
            END
            ,CASE WHEN @StartDate BETWEEN N'2023/02/01' and N'2023/05/01'THEN 1
                    WHEN @StartDate BETWEEN N'2023/09/01' and N'2023/11/29'THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
            END
    )

    SET @n += 1
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate)
END

SELECT  v.[Location]
        ,v.VacationDate
        ,SUM(v.InEu) OVER    (   ORDER BY    v.VacationDate ASC
                                    ROWS    179 PRECEDING
                                ) AS Test

FROM    #Vaca AS v

WHERE   1 = 1

GROUP BY    v.VacationDate
            ,v.[Location]
            ,v.InEu

ORDER BY    2 ASC
```

Comment: create a calendar table that contains all possible dates that you required. Flag the date with the required information.

Comment: That is another hard coded solution.  I was hoping for a solution where I could vary travel dates and see the impacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't intuit the simple rule that if you spend 90 days inside the Schengen, they you must spend 90 days outside the Schengen.  So all that is required are some variables and basic DATEADD functions.  So with 4 variables the trip start and end days can be shown with:

```
DECLARE @TripOneStart date = N'2023/02/01'
        ,@TripTwoStart date = N'2023/09/01'
        ,@TripOneDays int = 90
        ,@TripTwoDays int = 85

SELECT  @TripOneStart AS TripOnetartDate
        ,DATEADD(DAY, @TripOneDays, @TripOneStart) AS TripOneEndDate
        ,DATEADD(DAY, @TripOneDays * 2, @TripOneStart) AS EarliestTripTwoStartDate
        ,@TripTwoStart AS TripTwoStartDate
        ,DATEADD(DAY, @TripTwoDays, @TripTwoStart) AS TripTwoEndDate
        ,DATEADD(DAY, @TripTwoDays * 2, @TripTwoStart) AS EarliestTripThreeStartDate
```

I didn't bother to do the extra validation of ensure the second trip start is after the earliest possible return date.  The rowset gives you enough information to do any planning you might require.